# Five-pointed asterisk

Tags: symbols

Writing `*` or `\ast` produces a 6-pointed asterisk. How to write a 5-pointed one, like `\star`, but being an asterisk `*` not a star. Also, I don't want it to be a superscript, but an inline symbol, like `\ast` or `\star`.

Comment: Note that writing * in the body of this question produces a 5-pointed asterisk, but the same symbol in LaTeX produces a 6-pointed one.

Comment: Have a look at the `bbding` or `pifont` packages, they have a lot of different stars

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It's not there. I'm looking for something like \ding{81} but with 5 arms, not 6.

Comment: `\APLstar` from wasysym?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Didn't know that one, looks like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If you face similar problems in the future, maybe https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive could be helpful